# Catch closing event and prevent closing in console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I know how to solve this problem in c# form application, but now i want to do this in c++ console application

c# code:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

so basiclly i want to make console window unclosable (can only be closed with taskmanager under process tab)

Thanks

Comment: That's not possible.  You can get a callback for that with SetConsoleCtrlHandler() but that's just meant for cleanup.  It cannot be cancelled.  Don't use a console mode app if you cannot live with this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have any idea of concepts like *form*, *window* and *console*. You're likely using some additional framework than plain C++. Please, provide information about your environment (graphical library, operating system, development environment, etc.)

Comment: im new to c++... and i know i have to use SetConsoleCtrlHandler and catch CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, but i have no idea how... so i need help. im using visual studio 2012 and have windows 7

Comment: So, specify in the question that is Visual Studio and Visual C++, otherwise nobody will anser your question!